# 'safety dot' on rims

Tags: rims, hybrid-bike

My Araya GP-710 rims have a sticker that says 'safety dot' with arrows that point to little dimples in the rim -what are they for ? Dimple not visible in pic, but are on the rim

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**As long as you can see the dimple, the rim is still thick enough.**

When you brake, the rim gets worn. Eventually it is worn so thin that it can break. The dimples help you identify the wear so that you can replace the rim before it breaks.

Comment: Some have a groove instead, but the idea is the same

Comment: Thanks, that thought came to mind, but I wanted to check, I think its unlikely that's ever going to be an issue for me :-)

Comment: @Dagon You don't brake?